# Check user access after login

Tags: php, authentication, admin, boonex-dolphin

Ok so I have currently made a login system that validates the username/password from my Boonex Installation.

Once the user has been logged it I need the system to check if they have access to the 3rd part system.

To do this I have added a profile setting called Dashboard with the options if 1 or 0

Currently it is allowing access to all active users of the site regardless of wether Dashboard is tick in their profile
This is how I need the login process to work:

> User Logs In --> Page Redirects to Community Site to validate login details --> User redirected to dashboard page (index.php) --> If Dashboard = 1 stay on index.php else redirect to alternative age (Access Denied)

Here is the code I'm currently Using:

```
    // Call Required Files

    require_once( '/home/username/public_html/community/inc/header.inc.php'); //Only Used For File Paths And SQL


    require_once( BX_DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'profiles.inc.php' );  // Used for Getting Profile Details Such as name, email etc

    require_once( BX_DIRECTORY_PATH_INC . 'utils.inc.php' ); //  Not Current Used but will be in future.

    //Check for dashboard access

    $Dashboard_Check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE NickName = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID'])."'" ) or die(mysql_error());

    while($ROW = mysql_fetch_array($Dashboard_Check))

     {

        if('0' == $ROW['Dashboard']) {

            location('noaccess.php');


        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Don't use the deprecated MySQL_ statements. Use something more secure like PDO or MySQLi. Also, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Probs didnt explain it that well,
I need to check if the user has dashboard access from the SQL table Profiles after logging in.
If they dont then redirect them to noaccess.php

Comment: That's a BoonEx specific question, tagged as such.

Comment: Thanks,
I didn't tag it to Boonex as it only really uses the Profiles table and has no other interaction.

Comment: well, I don't know that platform, but you've got includes which look like they're part of it, and perhaps there are things to know about these in order to answer your question. The interactions between the DB and these scripts isn't clear for someone (like me) who doesn't know the platform and looks at your code.

Comment: The includes are not used as part of this query they just contain the data that will be used for the SQL Queries as well as collecting data on Forum posts etc. 

The only one that has any effect is the header.inc.php as this has all the SQL Info and the file paths